# Uploading to Google Drive in a separate thread in python

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-drive-api, python-multithreading

I am running into an issue where uploading to Google Drive in Python 3.6 in a separate thread is still seemingly blocking my main thread.

I am running a `flask` server (in a docker container) that on a request starts a separate thread which first downloads a file and then uploads it to Google Drive. Stripped of everything else, it's basically this:

```py
@app.route('/work')
def work():
    thread = Thread(target=handle, args=request.args.to_dict())
    thread.start()
    return 'Working'

def handle(args):
    filename = download_the_file(args)
    upload_to_drive(filename)

def upload_to_drive(filename):
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=appropriate_mimetype(filename))
    drive = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=CREDS)
    uploaded_file_id = drive.files().create(
        body={'name': filename},
        media_body=media,
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
    return uploaded_file_id
```

After the server starts the thread and responds to the request, any other request to the server are served okay, but only while it's downloading (`download_the_file` is using `requests.get(..., stream=True).iter_content()`. However, when the upload to Google Drive starts, any new requests hang until the upload finishes.

Any idea why it is and what can I do to keep the server responding?